# Bugzilla, no login required to view bugs

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, bugzilla

Bugzilla has to have a way to stop anyone random person to view the bugs, but I can't find it. This question is similar to How to prevent anonymous (users that are not logged in) BugZilla access?  but there is no answer to the question.

To elaborate further, as of right now, anyone can access my bugzilla server, and click on the Browse button to view any bugs we have listed. I've searched through all the administrative settings, and I can't find a way to disallow this. Surely it exists. Any help would be appreciated.

using Bugzilla 5.0.3

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Bugzilla-Anonymous-Access-td57781.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to Administration page, select User Authentication and then find the option "requirelogin".

Make sure it is checked as "ON"